# Meaning of てやる in 忘れてやらない

Tags: sentence, giving-and-receiving

Yes this the title of a song from Bocchi the Rock ("Never Forget"). Before learning about what てやる meant (I now do) it confused me, but even now the title still confuses me. I assume this usage has to do with volition and thus falls under :

③〈大胆(だいたん)／乱暴〉にそうする。
「答案を白紙で出してやった」

This makes sense, but I would then assume the title to be instead <strike>忘れなくてやる</strike> 忘れないでやる, rather than having やる in the negative. It seems like having it be やらない would **take away** the volition rather than emphatically "not forget". It don't know how one should take this.

Comment: The comparison should be with 忘れないでやる, not 忘れなくて.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*verb*-て(/で)やる is a condescending(/lighthearted/casual/joking) variation of *verb*-て(/で)あげる: to do you/someone the favor of *verb*. 
Hence, when you keep this "favor" giving implication (or negation thereof) in mind, the difference between the following two becomes obvious:

忘れてやらない: "I **won't** do you the favor of forgetting." 
(I won't let go of this grudge against you.)

忘れないでやる: "I'll do you the favor of **not** forgetting." 
(I'll remember this for your sake, being the benevolent guy that I am.)